# How to code a nested sql statement to get row number of a specific item in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to know how to get the row number of a specific item in mssql.

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
ID  Type      Brand     Model
1   Guitar    Ibanez    custom33 
2   Guitar    Ibanez    custom45 
3   Guitar    Ibanez    custom27 
40  Guitar    Fender    strat45 
41  Guitar    Fender    strat30 
42  Guitar    Fender    strat15
```

For example i want to get the items for Fender. I want the table to
be like this now(Assuming I'm using a select statement to get all the
items with the brand "Fender" in it):

```
ID   Type      Brand     Model 
40   Guitar    Fender    strat45 
41   Guitar    Fender    strat30 
42   Guitar    Fender    strat15
```

Then for example, I want to get the row number of Brand "Fender" and
Model "strat30". The returned value should be 2. If i want the Model
"strat15", the row number should be 3 and vice versa.

I probably might be needing to nest some sql syntax but i don't know how to 
combine the SELECT * FROM statement to SELECT ROW_NUMBER statement. Hope you guys can provide example for this.

Feel free to suggest the best way to achieve this output.

Comment: Provide Sample Data

Comment: guys check out my second question here in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918500/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-using-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use ROW_NUMBER(). In combination with WHERE clause, numbering will be applied only on results filtered by WHERE.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Rn 
FROM YourTable
WHERE Brande LIKE 'Fender'
```

And if  you really need just RN on specific model put this in subquery and select from it.

```
SELECT Rn FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Rn 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Brande LIKE 'Fender'
) x
WHERE x.Model LIKE 'Stat15'
```

Comment: but what if now i want to store the outcome of the code in a variabale using asp.net? I've tried this code:                                          
  string query = string.Format("SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS Rn FROM guitarItems WHERE Brands LIKE '{0}'", brand);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        X = count;

Comment: can you store the value in  Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();?

Comment: Use the second query to get Int32

Comment: If you have the time, kindly check out my second question here in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918500/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-using-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using a subquery and `ROW_NUMBER`.Add which ever model and brand you want in the outer `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
       SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Brand ORDER BY ID) RN
       FROM [YourTable]
       WHERE Type='Guitar' ) X
WHERE X.Brand='Fender' AND X.Model='strat30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` here. You'd need order criteria, e.g. the ID:

```
select rn
from
(
  select id, type, brand, model, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from mytable
  where brand = 'Fender'
) thebrand
where model = 'strat30';
```

Or:

```
select rn
from
(
  select id, type, brand, model, row_number() over (partition by brand order by id) as rn
  from mytable
) thebrand
where brand = 'Fender'
  and model = 'strat30';
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your reduced table into a temporary table named #Table (in this instance), and then use the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Model , 
    RowNumber
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Brand ORDER BY ID) RowNumber
    FROM 
        [#ReducedTable]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
--Here you get the row number of Brand "Fender" and Model "strat30". The returned value should be 2. 
--AND If you want the Model "strat15", the row number should be 3
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID INT,type NVARCHAR(50),Brand NVARCHAR(50),Model NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1,'Guitar','Ibanez','custom33' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Guitar','Ibanez','custom45' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Guitar','Ibanez','custom27'UNION ALL
SELECT 40,'Guitar','Fender','strat45'UNION ALL
SELECT 41,'Guitar','Fender','strat30'UNION ALL
SELECT 42,'Guitar','Fender','strat15'

Select ROW_NUMBER ()OVER (PARTITION BY Brand ORDER BY ID)Rownum, * INTO #T
FROM #TEMP 

SELECT * FROM #T 
WHERE Brand='Fender' AND Model='strat30'

DROP TABLE #TEMP
DROP TABLE #T

ROLLBACK TRAN
```